# Breeze: global overload fail function

Tags: breeze

Is there a way to **global** overload fail function?
For instance:

```
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from('Client');
        manager.executeQuery(query)
        //fail(myFunction) 
        // I don't want call 'fail' everytime.
        ;
```

Write now error is logging to the console. I would like to inject my implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your query thru another function before executing it

```
function executeQuery(q, manager) {
   return manager.executeQuery(q).fail(globalFailureHandler);
} 

function globalFailureHandler(e) {
  // custom code here
}
```

Then execute all of your queries like this

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from('Client');

executeQuery(query, manager).then(...);
```